# Using Arduino audio to control an LED light

Tags: led, remote-control, audio, signal-processing

I am looking for a way to control an LED on a circuit board using audio input for learning purposes.

I have written my own speech recognition system using dynamic time warping in Python, but I would like to know if (and maybe what models if not all can do) Arduino can possibly handle the processing of a 70 by 70 O(n^2) matrix traversal with **fft** or **dct** operations on audio input divided into 10ms frames.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Due or Tre may have enough power for this. The Yún may be able to offload it to the more powerful CPU. Every other Arduino will struggle with it.